# How to open only a bootstrap modal from iframe in current webpage on firefox add-on button click?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

I am developing a firefox plugin, And i want to open modal on add-on click,
for reference you can check Buffer add-on.
Buffer is inserting iframe into current page html.
my question is, How to insert iframe in current page ?

Comment: You would use pageMod - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod